# HTML pop up footer issues. 100% height problems

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer so that when clicked it pops up and fills the entire screen.
I do not know how to do this so the height is 100%.
I can do it with set pixels but I want it to fill the screen and not exceed the screen if a small window is open and reach halfway if its a big window.

If I set the footers container to 100% of the height the content and the animation will come to the top and animate downwards. Which it does 100% of the screen.

HTML

```
    <div id="footerSlideContainer">
            <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>
            <div id="footerSlideContent">


                <div id="footerSlideText">
                    <h3>blabla</h3>
                    <p>blablablabla.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>bla</li>
                        <li>Bla</li>
                        <li>bla</li>
                        <li>blabla</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>bedst i test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#footerSlideContainer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 5;

}
#footerSlideButton {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
position: absolute;
top: -60px;
width:100%;
height:120px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;

}
#footerSlideContent {
width: 100%;
height: 0;
background: white;
color: #CCCCCC;
font-size: 0.8em;
border: none;
-webkit-transition: height 700ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: height 700ms ease-in;
-ms-transition: height 700ms ease-in;
-o-transition: height 700ms ease-in;
transition: height 700ms ease-in;
}
#footerSlideContent.open {
height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Hey, if you want it to open up on the click that's unfortunately not possible with css. Are you opposed to using javascript? Here's a demo with javascript ('I included both the javascript and jQuery solution in case you had a preference'). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/6jLL7/ Just make sure that you put the script in the body if you use the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help in your situation:

```
#footerSlideContainer {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```